# Cancelling of Drag/Drop on DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I am using basic Drag/Drop functionality in single DataGridView.
Like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    dropindex = DataGridView1.HitTest(p.X, p.Y).RowIndex

    If (e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move) Then
        Dim dragRow As DataGridViewRow = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow)), DataGridViewRow)

        '' SOME PROCEDURE HERE FOR DROPPING ---
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_DragOver(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragOver
    e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseDown

    dragindex = DataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex
    If dragindex > -1 Then
        Dim dragSize As Size = SystemInformation.DragSize
        dragrect = New Rectangle(New Point(CInt(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2)), CInt(e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2))), dragSize)
    Else
        dragrect = Rectangle.Empty
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseMove

    If (e.Button And MouseButtons.Left) = MouseButtons.Left Then
        If (dragrect <> Rectangle.Empty AndAlso Not dragrect.Contains(e.X, e.Y)) Then
            Me.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.Rows(dragindex), DragDropEffects.Move)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

When I push left mouse button and start to drag some square appears under a cursor and dragging begins.
If I release button on certain row dropping occurs (normally:)

But, if during dragging I change a mind and press ESC key those square under cursor dissappears but dropping occurs anyway when I release button.

What to do to cancel dropping when dragging already begins (say with ESC key)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot track ESC by relying on the Key Event methods of the DataGridView, because are not triggered while you are drag-dropping. But there is an easy way to account for this situation (drag-drop process interrupted): `DragLeave Event`. You can make the condition for dropping depend upon a global flag set in this method. Sample code:

```
Dim cancelDrop As Boolean
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
    Dim p As Point = Me.PointToClient(New Point(e.X, e.Y))
    dropindex = DataGridView1.HitTest(p.X, p.Y).RowIndex

    If (e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move AndAlso Not cancelDrop) Then
        Dim dragRow As DataGridViewRow = CType(e.Data.GetData(GetType(DataGridViewRow)), DataGridViewRow)

        '' SOME PROCEDURE HERE FOR DROPPING ---
    End If
    cancelDrop = False
End Sub
Private Sub DataGridView1_DragLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragLeave
    cancelDrop = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Varocarbas. Your solution work, but I will still try to get solution without additional flags. If not, one additional boolean would be acceptable.

Comment: @user973238 Just one flag is not a big deal (actually, not a deal at all). Also I am afraid that the behaviour you report cannot be accounted for in many other ways: You might analyse the e.Data.GetData information to see if there is a property telling that or rely on another event (what I proposed), no big difference between both solution (in case that the first one is possible at all, what I don't know). Additionally, the global flag provides some information (dropping cancelled) that you might use somewhere else. But well... it is up to you.

Comment: Something surely happens when square dissapears. But I will accept your suggestion in order to get rid of concrete problem. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
   Me.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.Rows(dragindex), DragDropEffects.Move)
```

You made a mistake there.  The QueryContinueDrag event is raised on the control that called DoDragDrop().  You used *Me*, making the form the source of the data.  But you implemented the QueryContinueDrag for DataGridView1, not the form.  So your event handler never runs.  Fix:

```
   DataGridView1.DoDragDrop(DataGridView1.Rows(dragindex), DragDropEffects.Move)
```

Comment: Hah, I remove that code of QueryContinueDrag but Hans was too fast! I copy that code from subclass, that's why Me remains. Can I cancel dropping here without additional flags?